# How I get a file in Android SDK?

Tags: android, eclipse

How I get a file like images, mp3 or office file into android SDK(eclipse) for use it into my projects?

Comment: So you want to add a file to the emulator's sd card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use any file in your project, you may put it into `assets/` filder and access it later from your code as `context.getAssets().open( 'filename' )`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use it in your apk put into `res/drawable/` folder, then you can use it your code with `R.drawable.yourfile`